# Power Shell Community Extensions - Zip file not being created. Errors Encountered in ISE

Tags: powershell

I am almost done with my Power Shell script, however, I am trying to zip a folder containing images in a network share. I have added/imported the module called pscx for the Power Shell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com/). The zip file is not being created and I get errors in the ISE window.

The code that does the zipping is:

```
Import-Module Pscx
cd $ZipFileCreationDir
write-zip -path $FolderToCompress -outputpath $ZipFileName -noclobber -quiet -flattenpaths -level 9 | move-item $AS2OutgoingDir
```

The variables contain the following information:

```
$ZipFileCreationDir = "\\10.0.100.3\www2.varietydistributors.com\catalog"
$FolderToCompress = "newpictures"
$ZipFileName = "vdi.zip"
$AS2OutgoingDir = "\\10.0.100.3\AS2_Outgoing"
```

The errors encountered are:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'Pscx' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Desktop\ProcessOSImages.ps1:73 char:22
+         Import-Module <<<<  Pscx
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Pscx:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Write-Zip : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem' does not exist.
At C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Desktop\ProcessOSImages.ps1:75 char:18
+         write-zip <<<<  -path $FolderToCompress -outputpath $ZipFileName -noclobber -quiet -flattenpaths -level 9 | move-item $AS2OutgoingDir
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem:String) [Write-Zip], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Pscx.Commands.IO.Compression.WriteZipCommand
```

Please assist if you are able to. Thanks in advance. In short, I am trying to zip a folder located at \10.0.100.3\www2.varietydistributors.com\catalog\newpictures and then move the zip file to \10.0.100.3\AS2_Outgoing

I then changed the code to the following and then reran the script in the ISE:

```
    #Add-PSSnapin PSCX
    #. "$Pscx:ProfileDir\PscxConfig.ps1"
    #Import-Module Pscx
    cd "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ZipFileCreationDir"
    write-zip -path $FolderToCompress -outputpath $ZipFileName -noclobber -quiet -flattenpaths -level 9 | move-item "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$AS2OutgoingDir"
```

I then get the following errors:

```
Write-Zip : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem' does not exist.
At C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Desktop\ProcessOSImages.ps1:75 char:18
+         write-zip <<<<  -path $FolderToCompress -outputpath $ZipFileName -noclobber -quiet -flattenpaths -level 9 | move-item "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$AS2OutgoingDir"
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem:String) [Write-Zip], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Pscx.Commands.IO.Compression.WriteZipCommand
```

Comment: Okay. I have been playing around with this for a while now and have finally figured it out. Issue is resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out.